# How do I get a string out of mysql database to use with PasswordVerify()?

Tags: php, mysql

So  I have a database where the id, username and password is stored. The password is stored using php's `password_hash()` function. That part works fine, and it is successfully stored in the database with a hash. Now I want to use the `password_verify()` function. I cant seem to properly get the string value out of the database to use it with that function.

The database (`$db`) is properly set up due to the fact that I have already stored something in there.
Columns in database are just id, username and password.
$username and $password is what the user has filled in when logging in.

```
<?php
    if (count($errors) == 0) { // Everything correct, so verify pw
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0 ){
            $hashedpass = $sql->fetch_array();
            if (password_verify($password, $hashedpass['password'])); {
                $msg = "Username and password are correct";
            } else {
                $msg = "Incorrect";
        } else {
            $msg = "Incorrect";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are SQL injectable. Parameterize. What does `$hashedpass` come out as? How large is the `password` column?

Comment: @user3783243 an array...

Comment: @user3783243 it literally gives the value "Array"?

Comment: @Emerod Because it is an array, use the index. Don't use `echo` to debug. Use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: @user3783243 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty"
  ["password"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty"
}

Comment: Okay, so use the `0` or `password` index, as the other answers have stated.

Comment: @user3783243 yes I did that. And then with var_dump it gave me:  array(2) { [0]=> string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty" } But for some reason it still doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having fetched the data here, making `$hashedpass` an array:

```
$hashedpass = $sql->fetch_array();
```

Then you would compare against `$hashedpass['password']` using the column name from the table:

```
password_verify($password, $hashedpass['password'])
```

### Additionally

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: It just gives me the error: Notice: Array to string conversion in file x on line x

Comment: 'line x' does not tell me much. What is the actual line?

Comment: $Jay Blanchard literally line 131 in my script which is where I echo 'ed the $hashed pass. But I used var_dump() and then it gives me this output array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty"
  ["password"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$brD17zB2.RiYm1U6X4aUL.VHbjDUgMEYHeHdhunHae2LX97fg5kty"
}

Comment: Ah - then you know not to use echo. Did the code I provided for you work?

Comment: $Jay Blanchard sorry, I mixed up. With the code you provided (adding['password']) That came up as error. without the code you gave me it gave : the error: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string. Which was fixed because of your code. But the var_dump still gace me that.

Comment: Yes it did, technically. But now I have another problem, so I didnt fully work.

Comment: That problem requires another question.

Answer (score 0):

`$hashedpass = $sql->fetch_array();`

gives you an associative array with the column names you select.

You should get the values by selecting the correct element -

`$hashedpass['password']`